# Scala - Datastax Cassandra Connectivity Failure (with dse authentication enabled on cassandra cluster)

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using following code to authenticate datastax cassandra cluster (with dse authentication enabled) but i'm getting an exception. Could someone help me identifying & fixing the issue,

**code:**

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

object MySecondScalaWorksheet {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       
  def dseConnect(args: Array[String]){
      val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("server01.lab.east.com").withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra").build();
      val session = cluster.connect()
      println(session.getCluster())
    }                                         
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:64)
at MySecondScalaWorksheet$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(MySecondScalaWork
sheet.scala:6)
at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$$anonfun$$exe
cute$1.apply$mcV$sp(WorksheetSupport.scala:76)
at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.redirected(W
orksheetSupport.scala:65)
at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.$execute(Wor
ksheetSupport.scala:75)
at MySecondScalaWorksheet$.main(MySecondScalaWorksheet.scala:3)
at MySecondScalaWorksheet.main(MySecondScalaWorksheet.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Guava library is missing in your build setup. try adding the below in your sbt build file.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "21.0"
```